# How to reset the F6 IDE insight toolbar?

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-11-alexandria

Today, F6 IDE insight suddenly stopped working in Delphi 11 Alexandria in Design Mode:

[image]

When I enter, e.g., `TLabel` in the F6 search box, all palette components containing `TLabel` should be shown in the drop-down menu!

There is a remedy by Uwe Raabe here, but only for 10.2.3 Tokyo, as the **IDE Insight toolbar** in the Customize-Toolbars dialog is no more available in Delphi 11 Alexandria:

https://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2019/01/19/when-ide-insight-suddenly-stops-working/

How to fix this?

Comment: File a bug report in [Embarcadero's Jira](https://quality.embarcadero.com/).

Comment: To fix the problem right now, you should try to restart RAD Studio (obviously). You may also try to change desktop layout and try to remember if you have made any changes in RAD Studio or your projects lately.

Comment: If you still got Delphi 10.2, try to find out what the Reset button actually does (e.g. by exporting the Registry to a file before and afterwards and comparing these files). Maybe that can be done manually for Delphi 11.